# How to open sidemenu after entering a page?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic4 app with Google Firestore and I have some login in it. All I want is the sidemenu to be opened whenever I log into the application.

Something like: Login > PageX > *Open Sidemenu.
How can I do this?

This is the app page, which defines the menu content

```
    <ion-app>

      <ion-menu>

        <ion-header>

          <ion-toolbar color="primary">

            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>

          </ion-toolbar>

        </ion-header>

        <ion-content>

          <ion-list>

            <ion-item *ngIf="auth.usuario$ | async; then authenticated else guest">

            </ion-item>

            <ng-template #guest>

              <p text-center>Entre Utilizando Suas Credenciais</p>

            </ng-template>

            <ng-template #authenticated>

              <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">

                <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">

                  <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>

                  <ion-label>
                    {{p.title}}
                  </ion-label>

                </ion-item>

              </ion-menu-toggle>

              <div text-center *ngIf="auth.usuario$ | async as usuario">

                <ion-button color="secondary" (click)="auth.deslogar()">Logout</ion-button>

              </div>

            </ng-template>

          </ion-list>

        </ion-content>

      </ion-menu>

      <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>

    </ion-app>
```

Comment: you need to add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Ionic Side-Menu Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu) it shows that there is an `.open()` method available.

> **Description:**   Opens the menu. If the menu is already open or it can't
>   be opened, it returns false.
>
> **Signature:**    open(animated?: boolean) => Promise

A solution to have the side menu open by default after authenticating the user is to use the `.open()` method in the components `ngOnInit()` method.

For example in the component that gets loaded after authentication:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.menu.open();
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)